# How to sort a vector of structs?

Tags: sorting, rust, vector

Lets say I have some code like:

```rust
struct GenericStruct {
    a: u8,
    b: String,
}

fn sort_array(generic_vector: Vec<GenericStruct>) -> Vec<GenericStruct> {
    // Some code here to sort a vector.
    todo!();
}

fn main() {
    let some_words = String::from("Hello Word");
    let x = GenericStruct { a: 25, b: some_words };
    let some_vector: Vec<GenericStruct> = vec![x];
}
```

How could I sort vectors based on a portion, such as sorting by `a` or sorting by the length of `b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- implement the `Ord` trait for your struct and use the [`sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort)/[`sort_unstable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_unstable) methods
- use the [`sort_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by_key)/[`sort_unstable_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_unstable_by_key) methods

You'd use the former if, for your `generic_struct`, there is an *obvious* and *single* way to sort them that makes sense not just in your current sorting use case but generally.

You'd use the latter if this sorting scheme is more of a "one off".

```rust
somevector.sort_unstable_by_key(|element| element.a)
```

Comment: note the `sort_by_key` will also work, it has the advantage of being stable but is slower unless your data consists mostly of sorted runs.